# Angular Translation in JavaScript File

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have followed the [Angular translation example](http://blog.trifork.com/2014/04/10/internationalization-with-angularjs/) and html page translation is working by calling with filter, say `{{'TITLE' | xlat}}`

I want to use the translation in JavaScript file. I tried calling `$scope.xlat()`, `$xlat()` or `xlat()`.

How to refer and do the translation in JS file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be probably:

```
$filter('xlat')('TITLE')
```

Also, remember that '$filter' must be injected.